# Regex truncate string at the end

Tags: c#, regex

I have a set of complex file numbers and need to use Regex to filter as follows.

```
E/T66/2004Q/2009AA         --- remove  'AA'   ==> E/T66/2004Q/2009
E/T66/2004Q/2001 Vol1      --- remove ' Vol1' ==> E/T66/2004Q/2001
E/T66/2004Q/2001Vol1       --- remove 'Vol1'  ==> E/T66/2004Q/2001
E/T66/2004/123/3/1999 Pc3  --- remove ' pc3'  ==> E/T66/2004/123/3/1999
E/T78/2004A                --- remove 'A'     ==> E/T78/2004
```

I have used this Regex so far ([^/D]+$) to match last part after final '/'
I need to remove from where a non Digit is found to end of string at the end of the string.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Are there always 4 digits at the end of the "result" string?

Comment: @MarcB: does it matter? Surely half the joy of regex is not having to worry about that - you can tell it to have any number of digits and then just match the first non-digit that is asked for...

Comment: @AllTvRepairs, You need to make sure you mark Chris's answer as "Accepted". It's what makes the world go 'round.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Guys for all your feedback. I have tried them all and learned quite a lot from you! I ended up using the ".*/\d+" option here.

Answer (score 3):

Use this to remove the items you don't want `(\D+\d*)$`

Here's is an example of it working:
http://jsfiddle.net/BzyUL/4/

Comment: You could make that a little more versatile. Currently if he gets up to a vol10 this will fail. Similarly if there is a "vol 1a". These may not be possible but it was requested to remove everything after a non-digit so I'd have thought \D+.*?$ would do you pretty much... Also I think your \s? is redundant since the whitespace could as easily be captured by the \D+ after it I believe.

Comment: Chris, good call on the redundant \s?! I didn't think about the "Vol" getting up to 2 or more digits.

Comment: Look how much cleaner that is! I love collaborative work! I think the "?" following the "*" in your you suggestion isn't needed, your thoughts?

Comment: I was thinking of .*? to deal with if you have something like vol1a (not expected necessarily but nice to deal with unforseen things) but the non-greedy matching isn't sufficient for it to do what I wanted anyway (since it will always start trying to match at the beginning, succeed and with the $ at the end the .* has to consume everything left). So yes, in your example you don't need the "?" definitely.

Answer (score 3):

I would have thought it easier to define this in terms of what you want to keep rather than what you want to lose.

```
.*/\d+
```

The above will match all characters up to and including the final `/` and then any number of digits. This match will stop when it gets to the first non digit character which is where you are going to start throwing things away.

Sample code:

```
var re = new Regex("(.*/\\d+).*");
Console.WriteLine(re.Replace("E/T78/2004A", "$1"));
```

This works for all the above examples.

Comment: This doesn't account for the items ending in A or AA. But I agree, I think he needs to find a pattern in the filenames for the info he wants to keep.

Comment: @used2could: It works fine for the examples he gave above ending in A or AA. What do you think the problem is?

Comment: sorry at the time of my comment, there was only the ".*/\d+" pattern. Your example however works great!

Comment: Ah cool. Well that was the pattern that matched what was wanted. You could have used that on its own with matching rather than replacing, I was leaving the method of using it as a choice for the reader initially but then decided I should test it against all the examples and at that point I might as well paste in the working code. ;-)

Comment: Thanks Guys for all your feedback. I have tried them all and learned quite a lot from you! I ended up using the ".*/\d+" option here.

Comment: @AllTvRepairs: Don't forget to accept answers if you are happy with them. If you're unsure how then click the little tick next to the answr you found most helpful. It makes it easier for anybody else looking at this sort of question to see immediately what you thougth the best solution was.

Answer (score 0):

If there are always 4 digits at the end then `/(^.+\/\d\d\d\d)/` will match the part you want to keep in all the examples you gave. So just match the pattern and then replace the string with the matched string.

`/(^.+\/\d{4})/` There's a little bit shorter version for you.

Answer (score 0):

Use this regexp to match the full path or the file name only (no difference):

```
((\w+\/)*\d{4})(.*)
```

and replace it with `$1` as in:

```
var regexp = new Regex(@"((\w+\/)*\d{4})(.*)");
string result = regexp.Replace(path, "$1"));
```

to remove the unwanted characters after the year digits.